# Why don't anyone's parents live in Hogsmeade?

Tags: harry-potter

We know Hogsmeade is the only all-wizard town in Britain. So wouldn't some students' family live there? Not only is it a nice all-wizard place to live, but you would see your kids during Hogsmeade weekends. So why do we never hear about relatives living there?

Comment: In addition to all the information in the suggested duplicate and further duplicates from there on, we also don’t know how big Hogsmeade is. The few descriptions we get of the village make it sound quite small, perhaps no more than a couple of hundred residents. If that is the case, it wouldn’t be particularly unlikely if there happened to be no children around Harry’s age living there—it’s perfectly normal for small villages of that size to have only a few children at any given time.